# How can i use values that come out of a select statement using c#?

Tags: c#, sql, database, select, collections

I have a SQL server 2012 database that i wish to query it using a select statement and put every result the comes up in any sort of collection type say for example:   List

the problem is that i never ever did SQL Queering guys and i really need your help,

> I need to search for values in the tokens column in a table named "yt2016"... you can help me by writing the code i'll really appreciate it,  thanks in advance.

Comment: You've shown no effort, are basically asking for someone to do the work for you.. and you've tagged this with tags that don't relate to SQL..

Comment: "Be specific" it is written when you start asking a question.

Comment: You're going to to need to make a little effort yourself. If you search on google for `c#` `ado.net` `select` your first hit should be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx. That page has many examples to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Foo
{
    // some properties
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public static IEnumerable<Foo> GetAllFoos(String columnFilter = null)
{

    const string sql = @"SELECT 
                    Columns ...
                 FROM 
                    dbo.TableFoo
                 WHERE
                    @SomeColumn IS NULL OR SomeColumn = @SomeColumn
                 ORDER BY
                     OrderColumn1 ASC, OrderColumn2 DESC";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            if (columnFilter == null)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomeColumn", DBNull.Value);
            else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomeColumn", columnFilter);
            connection.Open();
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var list = new List<Foo>();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var foo = new Foo();
                    foo.Prop1 = rdr.GetInt32(0);
                    foo.Prop2 = rdr.GetString(0);
                    list.Add(foo);
                }
                return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A more tailored example might be

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DataAccess
{

    // This should be specific to your database.
    const string ConnectionString = 
        "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=true";

    const string TokenQuery @=
        "SELECT tokens FROM dbo.yt2016;"

    static IEnumerable<object> GetTokens()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
        // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
        var command = new SqlCommand(TokenQuery, connection);

        // Create and execute the DataReader, 
        // casting and yielding to the caller.
        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return reader[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jodrell: Thanks for the edit. However, `reader[0]` cannot be casted to `TToken` if that's a custom class. I would also stay with `using` even with the `yield` or do you think that's a problem?

Comment: thanks guys, and thanks for the people who gave me an advice to do more effort on learning first.

Comment: @user1999584: You might accept the answer anyway.